# Self-Hosted Gateway of API Manager 404 error

Tags: azure-api-management

Well I am having problems with the self-hosted gateway in an APIM.
I have followe this tutorials:

- For create an Azure API Management service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance
- For provisioning a self-hosted gateway: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-provision-self-hosted-gateway
- For deploy it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/how-to-deploy-self-hosted-gateway-kubernetes

All go well and the self-hosted gateway is running, the LoadBalancer service is good and has an external IP... Even I have this green check:
[image: green-check]

However, when I visit the Gateway URL: https://apim-example.azure-api.net I got: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" } on the browser.

I dont know why, because I have a Hello world! API example deployed and asingned to the gateway and, if, insteal of make a GET on https://apim-example.azure-api.net/example/kenny, I make the GET using the public Load Balancer IP Of the self-hosted gateway (https://XX.XX.XX.XX/example/kenny) the API response a 200 OK.

Have anyone idea of how to solve this? A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following all the given Microsoft documentations, I have created an APIM Instance, Self-hosted Gateway in it and added the Kubernetes deployment in the Gateway:

[image]

[image]

Then I created the basic Http Trigger in the Azure Function App and imported it in the Azure APIM Instance by adding the Self-Hosted Gateway in the Settings of that API:

[image]

Note: *For testing purpose, I have unchecked the "Subscription required" option*.

> However, when I visit the Gateway URL: `https://apim-example.azure-api.net`I got: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" } on the browser.

As given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-provision-self-hosted-gateway#provision-a-self-hosted-gateway), if we access the base URL without APIs, Response [Status Code 404](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/826562/azure-api-management-gives-404-error) will be displayed.

[image]

If API Name is passed to the Self-hosted gateway API of the APIM Instance, then the result is as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! 
I could swear that I tried to access the URL of the API, I even tried to test the API from the APIM and it gave me 404... But hey, it works now, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have deployed a new one api, and I have the same problem... 404 error, and Now I am doing the same... this is so strange....

Comment: Check the API URL once which should be quite similar to the one from the last screenshot

Comment: I did... But not work. But maybe I know where I have the problem. ¿is necesary have the both gateway, the managed and the selfhosted? I only have selected the selfhosted

Comment: i have one question on this matter. If we have both managed and selfhosted gateways. Does that mean both gateways can handle the requests?